# Xubuntu 22.04 problems

Tags: gui

my problems:

```
/usr/share/applications/kcm_trash.desktop
Exec program 'kcmshell5 kcm_trash' not found in PATH
```

Comment: Your "kcm_trash.desktop" file is invalid and tries to execute a binary (kcmshell5) that does not exist.  Looks like 3rd party software that wasn't installed correctly.
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME "gtk2" is correct. Some app expects the qt5c switch. Add `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct` into the /etc/environment file

Comment: @kanehekili QT fixed, thanks. I already know what it is. A basket from the dock called a plank. The kcm_trash.desktop file exists. How to fix?

Comment: check the "exec" line in the desktop file. `kcmshell5` does not exists as binary or is not executable

Comment: Exec=kcmshell5 kcm_trash